# Installer incorrectly flagging the same partition as two file systems

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

When installing Ubuntu 18.04 I get the below error during the partition setup of the guided install:

> Identical mount points for two file systems Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/boot/efi): MMC/SD card #1, partition #1 (mmcblk0p1) and MMC/SD card #1, partition #1 (mmcblk0p1). Please correct this by changing mount points.

There's only one MMC storage disk in the device. The only other thing plugged in is the USB stick being used to install this OS. What's the best way around this message?

Output of bikid:

```
~ # bikid
dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="FDBC-F1DF" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition PARTUUID="48203d68-1430-48e7-a134-c43e63ac59b4"
dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="62759374-4101-4351-a830-714dc40ao014" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="90073141-1084-46c9-aacb-db8b1cddd613"
dev/mmcblk0p3: UUID="fg07f514-c8f5-4729-adee-2db2218aea92" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="12f406a4-ee13-4672-acae-8bde2fb336ab"
dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="4610d626-17b2-4a85-b956-8b140cd7a0c9" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

then fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.1 GB, 31268536320 bytes, 61071360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4610D626-17B2-4A85-B956-8B140CD7A0C9

Device  Start   End Sectors Size    Type
dev/mmcblk0p1 2048  1050623     1048576     512M    EFI System
dev/mmcblk0p2 1050624   59070463    58019840    21.7G   Linux filesystem
dev/mmcblk0p3 59070464  61069311    1998848     976M    Linux swap

Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum optimal): 512 bytes  512 bytes

Disk /dev/mmcblk0boot0: 4 MiB 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector Size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The USB was created from the Ubuntu 18.04 minimal install ([mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)) and flashed onto the USB with [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) on a mac.

Comment: Check mounts and see if you can unmount one of them. It will want the ESP for UEFI install of grub. This was for installing to sdb, as Ubiquity only wants sda or first NVMe. It may be doing the same for your MMC drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Edit your question and show us `df` and `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l`. How did you build the USB install device? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the questions. I've updated with answers above.

Comment: Was there already something on the target SSD when you went to install?

Comment: Yes, it did have an earlier version of Ubuntu installed. I'd assumed by clearing the partitions and re-creating new ones any previous data wouldn't matter (as it would be deleted). Is that not correct?